# Android -- Are Android applications safe from outside illegitimate intrusion?

Tags: android, forum, financial, banking, onlinebanking

Well I have a concern, well talking to people on IRC Channel as well as seeing discussions on various android forums, I have been inclined towards the point that some of the android devices are vulnerable to outside intrusion because of some defects in Android OS (particularly because its open source and everyone is contributing to it). So its not better to use Android for Banking or similar applications . Is my perception right, or its otherwise and we can use it for such financial transaction like applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the android is powered by an opensource Operating System, it is still vulnerable to intrusions. Although its core is built by open source technology, it is still very susceptible to attacks.